# В некоторых проектах НЕ отображаются изменения в браузере без команды "npm run serve"

Tags: vue.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]Когда открываю на mac старый, давно забытый проект через webstorm, то все изменения html, css отображаются даже без сохранения(live edit), но когда создаю любой новый проект vue.js и сразу запускаю через 'npm run serve', то при редактирования кода изменения на странице не вижу. Не помогает даже сохранение и обновление страницы, а помогает только еще раз прописанная команда 'npm run serve'. Явно проблема ни в браузере или редакторе, а в самом проекте. На винде такой проблемы нет: новые, вручную созданные проекты без проблем работают с live edit без каких либо танцев с бубном. Весь интернет перерыл, но не нашел именной ТАКОЙ проблемы. Прошу помочь, уже крыша едет..

Comment: Добавьте минимальную конфигурацию которую запускаете с проблемой на mac. Возможно какая-либо библиотека для live edit установлена через -g параметр и она не работает с последней версией nodejs. Так же нужно проверить версии npm и nodejs, чтоб они были одинаковыми на mac и windows.

Comment: Добавил к телу впороса скрины package.json из проекта, который работает нормально с live edit( имя vuex) и из проекта, который вообще не видит изменений даже через f5(имя burger). С виндой сравнение было в том ключе, что на ней никогда такой проблемы не было(один и тот же проект и там и там я не открывал для проверки)
Версии на mac:
 node --version
v16.15.0
npm --version
8.14.0
 vue --version
@vue/cli 5.0.8
Если нужно доп. данные -  укажите, пож, какие именно, т.к. я новичок, пока не во всем ориентируюсь)
Спасибо

Comment: Лучше замените картинки на текст, трудно их воспринять. Версии cli-service в проектах отличаются, может попробовать их поменять, т.к. последняя не работает? Могу предложить включить расширенное логирование и посмотреть на наличие ошибок (должно быть что-то про `hot reload`). Так же попробуйте проверить все пути к файлам из-за различия ОС(mac и windows), имею ввиду `/`, `\` слеш и обратный слеш. Возможно есть какие-то права на доступ. Других догадок у меня нет.

Comment: Как внутри проекта можно поменять версию cli-service на более старую? Мне кажется наиболее вероятная причина

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решить проблему удалось переносом папки с проектом в корневой каталог вебшторма в папке юзерс. Каким образом нормально работали другие проекты из старого каталога решительно непонятно, однако решение найдено, пусть и при помощи костыля